# Customize Lynx's filetype behavior

Tags: configuration, lynx

I love `lynx`. I love browsing without tabs. Call me a luddite, but I only use a modern browser if I have to. Which is about twice a day, for a few minutes at most.

There's one thing I really really hate about `lynx`, though. It's not immediately apparent how to customize `lynx`'s behavior when it comes to filetypes.

If I encounter a .pdf file, it downloads it, then dutifully asks me if I'd like to save it to disk. Thanks, `lynx`. It's like you read my mind or something.

If I encounter a .torrent file, `lynx` downloads it, then opens it with `transmission-gtk`.

Uh... no, `lynx`. I would have either preferred `transmission-cli` or just having the torrent file.

If I try to open a magnet URL, `lynx` doesn't know what to do with it. (Psst! `transmission-cli`, `lynx`!

But the worst is when I download .ogg, because `lynx` assumes that I want to play it with VLC *in the TTY* using caca to render the video as ASCII.

Bad `lynx`!

How do I whip lynx into shape? How do I customize this behavior? Editing `/etc/lynx/lynx.cfg` does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: Lynx uses `mailcap(5)` to display non-HTML stuff. Have you considered using `elinks` or `w3m`?

Comment: Have you tried sending `lynx` to bed with no dinner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lynx does the standard thing (unlike Firefox and Chrome) and uses the system's [mailcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailcap) database. The system [mailcap](http://linux.die.net/man/4/mailcap) is in `/etc/mailcap`, and the per-user file is `~/.mailcap`. Add entries like

```
application/x-bittorrent; transmission-cli '%s'; needsterminal
application/pdf; pdftotext '%s'; copiousoutput
application/ogg; vlc '%s'; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted, Lynx uses the standard [mime-types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) and  [mailcap](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1524) files to decide what a file's *type* is and how to *present* it, allowing customization by the user.

The locations of the system- and user-mailcap files are configurable (in `lynx.cfg`):

- [GLOBAL_MAILCAP](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#GLOBAL_MAILCAP), e.g., `/etc/mailcap`
- [PERSONAL_MAILCAP](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#PERSONAL_MAILCAP), e.g., `~/.mailcap`

and the mime-type files likewise are configurable:

- [GLOBAL_EXTENSION_MAP](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#GLOBAL_EXTENSION_MAP), e.g., `/etc/mime.types`
- [PERSONAL_EXTENSION_MAP](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#PERSONAL_EXTENSION_MAP), e.g., `~/.mime.types`